# Upgrading Vultr "One Click" Wordpress to PHP7 on CentOS 6

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, centos, php-7

Trying to upgrade the Vultr "One Click" Wordpress to PHP7

https://www.vultr.com/docs/one-click-wordpress

```
sudo yum -y update
yum list installed php*
sudo yum -y remove php56u*
sudo yum -y install php70u-cli.x86_64 php70u-common.x86_64 php70u-fpm.x86_64 php70u-gd.x86_64 php70u-mbstring.x86_64 php70u-mcrypt.x86_64 php70u-mysqlnd.x86_64 php70u-opcache.x86_64 php70u-pdo.x86_64 php70u-pear.noarch php70u-process.x86_64 php70u-xml.x86_64 php70u-xmlrpc.x86_64
sudo chkconfig php-fpm on
service nginx restart && service php-fpm restart
php -v
```

The above appears to be working, but now wordpress asks me for FTP credentials every time I change something. I have checked the credentials on the wordpress directory and everything appears to be ok!?

What am I missing!?

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo chown nginx:nginx * -R
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
service nginx restart && service php-fpm restart
ls -l
```

Gives the output below (which I believe is the correct user and group).

```
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx   418 Sep 25  2013 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx 19935 Mar  5 20:14 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  7360 Apr 26 20:25 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  5032 Jan 28 03:35 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 nginx nginx  4096 May  6 18:33 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx   364 Dec 19 11:20 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  1476 Jan 30 21:56 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  1590 Jun  4 02:46 wp-config.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  2853 Dec 16 09:58 wp-config-sample.php
drwxr-xr-x  6 nginx nginx  4096 Jun  4 02:49 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  3286 May 24  2015 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 16 nginx nginx 12288 May  6 18:33 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  2380 Oct 24  2013 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  3316 Nov  5  2015 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx 33837 Mar  6 03:06 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  7887 Oct  6  2015 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx 13106 Feb 17 22:58 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx 28624 Jan 28 03:51 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  4035 Nov 30  2014 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nginx nginx  3061 Oct  2  2015 xmlrpc.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem! Needed to up the php7 configuration to change the user and group.

```
sudo nano /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
    user = nginx
    group = nginx
service nginx restart && service php-fpm restart
```